# Searching for an exact match with a singular digit

Tags: vim

I'm trying to search for only a singular digit in vim by itself. For example, if there are two sets of digits 1 and 123 and I want to search for 1, I would only want the singular 1 digit to be found.

I have tried using regular expressions like \<1> and \%(a)@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had the right solution. You want:

```
\<1\>
```

This is because each angled bracket needs to be escaped. Alternatively, you could use:

```
\v<1>
```

The `\v` flag tells vim to treat more characters as special without needing to be escaped (for example, `(){}+<>` all become special rather than literal text. Read `:h /\v` for more on this.

A great reference for learning regex in vim is [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/). The `\<\>` characters are explained in 4.1 "Anchors".

---

If you want to match text like `1.23` this is possible too. Two different approaches:

1. Modify the `iskeyword` option so that it includes `.`. This will also affect how `w` moves
2. Use `\v<1(\d|.)@!`, which basically means "a 1 at the beginning of a word, that **isn't** followed by some other digit or a period."

Comment: I should probably reword my question. I was using \<1\>, but since there are also a significant number of floating point numbers, numbers like 1.23, for example, would be found with \<1\>. Would there be a way to remove this decimal point?